# Why there is no "Select Mock Location App"?

Tags: android

On my Android device with version Lollipop with the Qualcomm Snapdragon chipset, I don't have the **Select Mock Location App** feature in the developer options. Instead I have a **Allow Mock Location** checkbox. Why does my friend has the options to select a app, and I don't?

Answer (score 4):

You do not necessarily need the **Select Mock Location App**, this is for allowing one specific application for using mock locations. If you have older versions of the Android OS you only have the **Allow mock location** setting for turning this feature on or off.

In short, when turning **Allow Mock Location** ON you can start a app of your own choice and mock your location, your friend needs to select which applications that's allowed to do this.